# Delete list of Azure Resource Groups in a subscription without confirmation using Azure ClI

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-resource-group

I want to delete all the resource groups in a subscription in a single cli command. I used pipeline operator to delete all the resource groups:

(Get-AzResourceGroup | Remove-AzResourceGroup).

While azure deletes the groups sequentially, it prompts for confirmation for each resource group. Is there a way to force delete all resource groups in Azure cli without encountering the confirmation from the CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `-Force` parameter to remove resource group without confirmation.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/remove-azresourcegroup?view=azps-8.0.0#example-2-remove-a-resource-group-without-confirmation):

```
Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "ContosoRG01" | Remove-AzResourceGroup -Force
```

> This command uses the Get-AzResourceGroup cmdlet to get the resource
> group ContosoRG01, and then passes it to Remove-AzResourceGroup by
> using the pipeline operator. **The Force parameter suppresses the
> confirmation prompt**.

Comment: the command will remove only a specific resource group, not all resource groups in a given subscription.

Comment: The command I mentioned was from the documentation to show the usage of `-Force`. Can you try `(Get-AzResourceGroup | Remove-AzResourceGroup -Force)`?

Answer (score 1):

We can use this power shell script to delete all resource groups in a subscription.
Delete All resource groups whose names match with the filter

```
$filter = 'rg-devenvironment' 
Get-AzResourceGroup | ? ResourceGroupName -match $filter | Remove-AzResourceGroup -AsJob -Force
```

Comment: Hello @karunakarbhogyari, could you upvote my question if this would helps the other users in the community who faces/needs similar issue/requirement.