# How to delete all resource groups forcibly without prompt for confirmation using Azure CLI cmdlets?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

Found the similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72824400/19615125) but answer is in Azure PowerShell.

Tried the below cmdlet to delete all resource groups in particular location:

```
az group list --query "[?location=='westus']".name -o tsv | xargs -otl az group delete -n
```

It is asking me to prompt for every resource group deletion.

Also tried adding the flag `-y` by reading this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-delete-examples),

```
az group list --query "[?location=='westus']".name -o tsv | xargs -otl az group delete -n -y
```

Error:

```
az group delete -n -y rg-105
argument --name/-n/--resource-group/-g: expected one argument
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
az group list --query "[?location=='westus']".name -o tsv | xargs -ot -n 1 az group delete -y -n
```

Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/1398#issuecomment-276135930

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri,  If resource groups are in multiple locations, I tried to delete them with the above comdlets like `az group list --query "[?location=='westus' && 'eastus' && 'centralIndia']".name -o tsv | xargs -ot -n 1 az group delete -y -n` but it's not deleting all the resource groups present in mentioned locations. Why, any syntax mistake?

Comment: Please check the output of your first CLI command. I think you’re not getting the right result there.

Comment: The cmdlet you have given working for me and I'm asking how to specify the multiple locations in the same cmdlet!

Comment: I have no idea, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here I am deleting all resource groups in two locations using OR(||) operator and specified -y for running command without user consent or confirmation.

az group list --query "[?location=='centralindia'|| location=='eastus']".name -o tsv | xargs -otl az group delete -y -n

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.